# Using grep to return the first word of each rowname in R (with underscore separators)?

Tags: regex, r

I wish to use grep to return the first word each rowname in R. Rownames have the format `Firstword_secondword_thirdword`, and I need to return the first word, excluding the underscore.

I'd usually nut it out on my own but I'm quite pressed for time!

Comment: One way: `gsub("(^[a-zA-Z]+)_{1}.*$" , "\\1" , "Firstword_secondword_thirdword" )`. But please, write a better question in future following the posting guidelines (informally for the `r` tag read [**how to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381) ). Being in a rush is not likely to earn you sympathy on this site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strsplit`. Consider this example:

```
> string <- c("Firstword1_secondword1_thirdword1", 
              "Firstword2_secondword2_thirdword2",
              "Firstword3_secondword3_thirdword3")
> words <- strsplit(string, "_") # split string by '_'
> sapply(words, "[", 1)          # getting just first word 
[1] "Firstword1" "Firstword2" "Firstword3"
```

**Update**

You can use a simpler approach with `sub`

```
> sub("(\\w)\\_.*", "\\1", string)
[1] "Firstword1" "Firstword2" "Firstword3"
```

Comment: Even better than grep; thanks!

Comment: Hi Jilber, i had a similar case, however, in my case  "words" includes clumps of number e.g. 12345 lorem ipsum should return 12345. How would i modify the regex to includes numbers too

Comment: @FirhatNawfanH suppose your string is `string <- "12345 lorem ipsum"`, then you can use `gsub("[^0-9]+", "", string)` or `sapply(strsplit(string, " "), "[", 1)`

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that my data set consist of rows like "12345 lorem ipsum" and "abcde lorem ipsum" i wanted the regex to capture first clumps of character that is numeric or alphabet

Comment: @FirhatNawfanH. I think you can do it this way:`sapply(strsplit(as.character(df[, 1]), " "), "[", 1)` if not, then put your problem as a new question providing a small sample of your dataset and your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

`regexpr` and `regmatches` are for precisely this task.

```
#Find position and length of first match
x <- regexpr( "^[a-zA-Z]+(?=_)" , "Firstword_secondword_thirdword" , perl = TRUE )
# Extract it
regmatches( "Firstword_secondword_thirdword" , x )
[1] "Firstword"
```

The pattern in `regexpr` is from the start of the string (`^`) match one or more alphabetic characters (`[a-zA-Z]+`) that are followed by a single underscore (the positive lookahead assertion, `(?=_)`).